# 与世 How best translate in english

Tags: characters

could please someine help me making sense of the following two hanzi characters 与世？

Literally it would mean "and the world" but for me it does not fit into the following idioms :

与世无争
yǔ shì wú zhēng
to stand aloof from worldly affairs 
与世长辞
yǔ shì cháng cí
to die

与世永别
yǔ shì yǒng bié
to die

Answer (score 8):

与 would mean **"with"** here, like 跟, to connect a noun.

与世无争 would then mean "not strife with the world", to keep a low profile, to lead a life in moderation and self-restraint.

与世长辞 is likewise a statement of a person and the world, namley that of taking a long farewell from the world, to leave this word, or less prosaic: to die. 长 here has the notion of 长久, for a very long time, or forever, like in the famous poem 但愿人长久.

与世永别 is similarly to part forever from the world.

Comment: Nice explanation! +1